# Javascript code: dynamically change currencies with dropdown HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have been looking for this all day - Change currencies throughout the page when choosing between countries or currencies from dropdown menu.

What I basically need is a dropdown menu which shows countries or currencies. When you select anyone of it like USD all the prices throughout the page are changed to USD. Now if you change it AUD/CAD/PKR etc they will be changed accordingly. I basically need it in Javascript but if anyone can provide it in PHP, it would be okay too.

A very good example of this is: http://creativeon.com When you change currency from right top dropdown menu - it changes the currencies of all the packages in the main content.

I am a HTML developer and do not know much about javascript. Please help me.

P.S. I have searched codingforums.com too and found only two links which are not of my use because they are currency converter:

1. http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=196577
2. http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=196373

Comment: You should start learning programming and ask programming questions not for scripts...

Comment: Doing these kinds of conversions, on the fly, is fraught with danger, unless you are actually billing them in all your listed currencies (as, if you are billing in USD, but you have displayed the prices in CAD and the exchange rates change, they will be billed a different price to what they were quoted). Better to stick with one currency and leave the conversion up to the client to find their own resources to calculate. Or, failing that, hire a coder to make this for you - No free lunches here.

Comment: This reads a bit like a 'give meh teh codez please, kthxbye' question. We are not here to give you full working solutions. We are here to help you out if you get stuck. Furthermore, your question probably doesn't limit itself to a frontend problem only. You'll probably need interaction with a backend to get the prices in other currencies, unless the backend has already provided them in some javascript dataobject for instance.

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of webapps is that you can borrow good ideas by looking a the source code (using a toll like the Firebug plugin in FF). As you can see in the example you mention the page is reloaded when a different currency is chosen:

```
$('#Items, #Items_input').change(function(){
    $.post('/conlogic/ajax.php?action=currency',
        {'curr': $(this).val()},
        function(data){
            if ( data=="OK" ) window.location.reload();
        });
});
```

Apparently in this case the page is re-rendered server side with the different currency.

Answer (score 1):

I write a javascript version. no Ajax, currency change rates was borrowed from google.

**HTML Code**

```
  <select id="currencySelector">
    <option value="usd">USD</option>
    <option value="aud">AUD</option>
    <option value="eur">EUR</option>
    <option value="gbp">GBP</option>
  </select>
  <div class="currency" data-currencyName="usd">15<span>USD</span></div>
  <div class="currency" data-currencyName="eur">15<span>EUR</span></div>
  <div class="currency" data-currencyName="gbp">15<span>BGP</span></div>
  <div class="currency" data-currencyName="aud">15<span>AUD</span></div>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
var 
    selector = document.getElementById("currencySelector");
var
    currencyElements = document.getElementsByClassName("currency");
var 
    usdChangeRate = {
      AUD: 1.0490, // 1AUD = 1.0490 USD
      EUR: 1.4407, // 1EUR = 1.4407 USD
      GBP: 1.6424,
      USD: 1.0
    };

selector.onchange = function () {
    var 
        toCurrency = selector.value.toUpperCase();

    for (var i=0,l=currencyElements.length; i<l; ++i) {
        var 
            el = currencyElements[i];
        var 
            fromCurrency = el.getAttribute("data-currencyName").toUpperCase();

      if (fromCurrency in usdChangeRate) {
          var 
              // currency change to usd
              fromCurrencyToUsdAmount = parseFloat(el.innerHTML) * usdChangeRate[fromCurrency];
          var 
              // change to currency unit selected
              toCurrenyAmount = fromCurrencyToUsdAmount / usdChangeRate[toCurrency];

          el.innerHTML = toCurrenyAmount + "<span>" + toCurrency.toUpperCase() + "</span>";
          el.setAttribute("data-currencyName",toCurrency);
      }
    }
};
```

**Run the code**

You can run the code above at http://jsbin.com/ewuyoq/5 or build your own version http://jsbin.com/ewuyoq/5/edit

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery, so feel free to disregard my answer if you don't want to use an external library. It can be found on www.jquery.com.

First, you make a span for all places where currency should be changed, give it class "currency" and in the name attribute, you put the value in your "base currency". Example:

```
<span class="currency" name="499"> 499 </span>
```

Then you can make a button, say it has id "showInEuro".

```
<input type="button" id="showInEuro" />
```

Then write some jQuery code similar to this:

```
var usdToEuroExchRate = 1.5; // Obviously just a magic constant

// When the button is clicked
$("#showInEuro").click(function() {
     // Iterate through all of the currency spans
    $("span.currency").each(function(index) {
        // And take their names times the exchangerate and put it in the span.
        $(this).text($(this).attr("name") * usdToEuroExchRate);
    });
});
```

Of course, you should try to use real, live exchange rates.

I made a JSFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/An3v9/9/